# emberjs - output creates a messy script tag

Tags: ember.js

I'll be as brief as possible: I want to display people, with "url"-s as their profile picture. This is the .js code:

```
App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Images.find();
    }
});

App.Images.FIXTURES = [
{
    id:1,
    name: "John Doe",
    sizeX: 180,
    sizeY: 180,
    url: 'bg.jpg'
}];
```

However, the image does not get displayed and what this actually does, is this:

```
<img src="img/<script id='metamorph-6-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>bg.jpg<script id='metamorph-6-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>" alt="">
```

Comment: can you post your handlebars template where the `img` tag lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `unbound` to make sure the metamorph tags are not added:

in your template:

```
<img src="img/{{unbound url}}" alt="">
```

This should just print out the value of the `url` property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If the url can change, you should have a look at the `{{bindAttr}}` helper, because the unbound helper does not update the DOM automagically. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bindAttr

Comment: @mavilein, thanks for your suggestion, you are right, the thing here is that he has a `img/` prefix in his image src property, this would create the additional need to define a property on the view or controller to construct the final `url`